# Difference between Basic Conference and Global Conference

Tags: twilio

What is the difference between Basic Conference and Global Conference in Twilio other than the number of participants?
If a Basic Conference is made by the non US locale users, will it affect the quality of the call or will it change automatically to 
Global Conference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Global conference uses our Global Low Latency network, that is, when people dial into your conference their audio will be routed via the closest servers in order to reduce latency.

Basic conference will just use our servers in Virginia, USA. So calls made outside of the US may suffer latency issues.

There is a good visualisation of this effect on the [Conference product page](https://www.twilio.com/voice/conference).

Comment: Thanks! Also I want to know how to turn on / off Global Conferencing feature.

Comment: You can switch between Basic/Global Conference in your Twilio console here: https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings/conferences